# Is there a way to get the `metadata.depth` value also be added to a field in the doc index?

Tags: elasticsearch, stormcrawler

Stormcrawler, through the process of crawling, is adding a field to the status index called `metadata.depth`.  I am not sure where that is generated from, but would it be possible to somehow send that depth value to the, er, index index in elasticsearch as well as the status index?  That value would help a bit with ranking for searching against the index index.

Comment: what have you tried so far? BTW that index is now called 'content'

Comment: I have not 'tried' anything, except to try to figure out where the `metadata.depth` is being generated from. So far I have had no luck. Where should I look to try to figure out where this value is calculated from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the metadata, it can be indexed using *indexer.md.mapping*, like anything else.

It is generated by [MetadataTransfer](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/util/MetadataTransfer.java#L156) when an outlink is discovered.

Comment: OK, so I have tried both adding `  - depth=depth` as well as removing that and adding  `- metadata.depth=depth` to the `indexer.md.mapping` setting in the crawler-conf.yaml and restarted the crawler. Neither seems to make a difference, and the `depth` field does not show up in the main index. Thoughts?

Comment: Oops. Never mind. I was looking at the wrong index. {facepalm}. `- depth=depth` did the trick.  Thanks!